# If two atoms join, do they lose their original spectral lines?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, resonance

Each element and even isotope of element has its own set of unique spectral absorption lines. What happens to these lines after two or more atoms join together into molecule?

Are all of the lines that pure element has in monoatomic form lost? Or is it that some or all lines are preserved?

Also, does it depend on the type of bond (ionic, covalent)?

Comment: The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. 

Effort not shown can be considered as effort not done and such a question may be  closed.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not homework question. All my research was googling it and not finding anything relevant. I decided to not even mention my research to shorten my question as I found people have short attention span and are more likely to read and respond to shorter text.

Comment: On CH SE, the shorter the question, the higher risk to be closed, instead of being responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which part of the spectrum you're looking at, for different parts of the spectrum involve different electrons.

Visible and UV spectra involve transitions of the valence electrons, which certainly change their states as atoms are joined chemically. The colors we see in chemical substances, such as iodine vapor being purple or nitrogen dioxide being brown, arise from such spectral shifts.

When we move to the far UV and X-ray portions of the spectrum, which involve transitions of more tightly bound inner electrons, this changes. These inner electrons remain in essentially the same quantum states. The spectral lines associated with them remain largely intact with only minor variations. X-ray methods for identifying elemental composition, such as energy-dispersive spectroscopy, rely on this constancy.

Comment: O2 is not blue in the gas state the blue color is from molecular association in the liquid and solid.

Comment: There is a 2-paged article in the Journal of Chemical Education on the blue color of liquid oxygen. Here at https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed042p647 and they have a very different explanation of this beautiful color. They say it is a phenomenon in which a single photon excites two electrons in two different O2 molecules which have collided.

Comment: This is getting long due to comments that no longer apply because of answer edits. May want to remove.

Comment: Thank you very much Oscar Lanzi , this was excellent answer, just what I was trying to find.

Answer (score 2):

The lines of the atomic spectra are not maintained in the spectrum of the molecule. For example, the hydrogen atom lines are defined by the so-called Lyman, Balmer, Paschen, etc. series. The hydrogen molecule do not show these lines. It has its own series of lines.

Comment: Is it always like that in all molecules? I mean, did they never find even one spectral line being preserved in all molecules that were ever examined?

Comment: Slightly amplifying what Maurice said, isolated atoms have atomic emission lines in the IR, visible and UV spectral regions. But atoms in molecules are not isolated, so they do not have those atomic emission lines. Instead, molecules have a richer set of opportunities to absorb or emit light.

Comment: Just to emphasize what Maurice says in his answer, that I upvoted a year ago, here I show my two dimensional spectrum of the light emitted by my hydrogen discharge tube: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768678/313612. The high voltage discharge results in some hydrogen molecules dissociating to atoms. Then light can be emitted from excited hydrogen atoms, e.g., the Balmer series shown, plus light can be emitted from excited hydrogen molecules, e.g., the Fulcher alpha bands.